# Firebase removeValue()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem to write a code to delete database.
I would like to delete this:

[image: image1]

I don't know how to use `.child()` in this situation. My code for now is:

```
    private void deleteKryterium(String kryteriumId) {
    DatabaseReference drKryteria = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(kryteriumId);

    drKryteria.child(kryteriumId).removeValue();

    Toast.makeText(this,"Kryterium zostało usunięte", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

But it is wrong. Can you help me? Most of the code I wrote from tutorials, so it's very green.
On the other side code which is designated to update this `child`, is working fine:

```
private boolean updateKryterium(String id, String name, int rating){

    Kryterium kryterium = new Kryterium(id, name, rating);

    databaseKryteria.child(id).setValue(kryterium);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Nazwa kryterium zaktualizowana", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not pointing to the correct reference you want to remove.

The path to that child should start from:

```
DatabaseReference drKryteria = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("piwo_kryteria");
```

Then at that point, you should move to the child with key -LI785bPiLU9Z2qEe35o and then finally to the child you want to remove (with id kryteriumId). 
You should know the value of the intermediate key as you do for the kyteriumId.

Notice that you can also use 1 single child() function passing to it the entire path in which each node is separated by forward-slashes like:

```
.child("piwo_kryteria/" + intermediate_key + "/" + kryteriumId)
```

On that reference you will call removeValue() or even setValue(null).

Comment: I'm sorry, the image is after changes i did, i already have a code like you wrote:
DatabaseReference drKryteria = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("piwo_kryteria");

Comment: ok and then you set the correct path to the element you want to remove?

Answer (score 0):

this is a code for now, ofcourse it is not working correctly in deleting items:

```
public class Piwo_AddKryterium extends AppCompatActivity {


TextView textViewAlkoholName, textViewRating;
SeekBar seekBarRating;
Spinner spinnerKryteria;
Button buttonAddKryterium;
ListView listViewKryteria;
DatabaseReference databaseKryteria;
List<Kryterium> kryteria;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.piwo_activity_add_kryterium);

    textViewAlkoholName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAlkoholName);
    seekBarRating = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarRating);
    textViewRating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRating);
    buttonAddKryterium = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddKryterium);
    listViewKryteria = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewKryteria);
    spinnerKryteria = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerKryteria);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    kryteria = new ArrayList<>();

    String id = intent.getStringExtra(Piwo_Program.ALKOHOL_ID);
    String name = intent.getStringExtra(Piwo_Program.ALKOHOL_NAME);

    textViewAlkoholName.setText(name);

    databaseKryteria = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("piwo_kryteria").child(id);

    buttonAddKryterium.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            saveKryterium();
        }
    });
    seekBarRating.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

            textViewRating.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    listViewKryteria.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }
    });

    listViewKryteria.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Kryterium kryterium = kryteria.get(i);

            showUpdateDialog(kryterium.getKryteriumId(), kryterium.getKryteriumName());

            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    databaseKryteria.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            kryteria.clear();

            for(DataSnapshot kryteriumSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Kryterium kryterium = kryteriumSnapshot.getValue(Kryterium.class);
                kryteria.add(kryterium);
            }

            KryteriumList kryteriumListAdapter = new KryteriumList(Piwo_AddKryterium.this, kryteria);
            listViewKryteria.setAdapter(kryteriumListAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void saveKryterium(){
    String kryteriumName = spinnerKryteria.getSelectedItem().toString();
    int rating = seekBarRating.getProgress();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(kryteriumName)){
        String id = databaseKryteria.push().getKey();

        Kryterium kryterium = new Kryterium(id, kryteriumName, rating);

        databaseKryteria.child(id).setValue(kryterium);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Kryterium zapisane poprawnie", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Nazwa kryterium nie może pozostać pusta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void showUpdateDialog(final String kryteriumId, String kryteriumName){

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.piwo_update_dialog_kryterium, null);

    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);


    final Spinner spinnerKryteria = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerKryteria);
    final Button buttonUpdate = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
    final SeekBar seekBarRating = (SeekBar) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.seekBarRating);
    final Button buttonDelete = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);

    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Aktualizacja Kryterium: " + kryteriumName);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String kryteriumName = spinnerKryteria.getSelectedItem().toString();
            int rating = seekBarRating.getProgress();


            updateKryterium(kryteriumId, kryteriumName, rating);
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            deleteKryterium(kryteriumId);
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });


}

private void deleteKryterium(String kryteriumId) {
    DatabaseReference drKryteria = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(kryteriumId);

    drKryteria.child(kryteriumId).removeValue();

    Toast.makeText(this,"Kryterium zostało usunięte", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

private boolean updateKryterium(String id, String name, int rating){

    Kryterium kryterium = new Kryterium(id, name, rating);

    databaseKryteria.child(id).setValue(kryterium);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Nazwa kryterium zaktualizowana", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return true;
}
```

}